# Mentioning someone will not send any email notifications

Tags: 2013, user-profile, administration, mysite, social-feed

I am working an a sharepoint on-premises 2013. and inside the personal site i defined the following, mainly to get notified when someone mention me , as follow:-

[image]

so now some users have mentioned me in some Newsfeed and community sites, but i did not receive any emails. although the mention have appeared inside the personal site >> Newsfeed >>Mentions tab, as follow:-

[image]

but i think i am supposed to receive email notifications also based on my settings? is this correct ?

Answer (score 4):

Is the outgoing email server correctly configured in the farm and My Site host web application? Have you tested other notifications like site sharing invitations? If those don't work you may need to set up your SharePoint farm as a trusted referrer in Exchange.

Comment: now in my case i only have 2 web applications; Site Administration & the one i am using to create site collections and where the my-sites will be created.. and inside the site collections user notifications + emails sent inside the workflow are working well... so i think the email configurations are correct for the web application is this correct ? but not sure if this mean that i SharePoint farm is set as a trusted referrer in Exchange ??

Comment: I would test the OOB send mail, like Alerts or Site Membership notifications. Failing that I would watch the ULS logs for User Profile Service mail issues.

Comment: now as i mentioned before the OOB send mail, like Alerts or Site Membership notifications. are working on the site collections.. but the notifications for the Mentions are not working..

Comment: can you adivce on my comments please?

Comment: Not without more information. You said that the regular send mail is working. If that is the case I would crank up the logging and check the ULS logs while you fire the error.